# Can't get Phone Gap Facebook auth working on both IOS and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I'm developing a phone gap app that uses facebook Auth. If I use the following tag to import the facebook javascript sdk from a local file.

```
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
```

My ios app works when deployed to my iphone but not on a Chrome desktop browser and Chrome inspector produces the following error:

The Desktop site crashed with a  message of

```
HEAD http://www.{my_url_name}.com/!gap_exec?1385512562554 404 (Not Found) cordova.js:970
iOSExec cordova.js:970
CDV.FB.init cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js:16
FB.provide.init facebook-js-sdk.js:7317
(anonymous function) fb_mobile.js:30
Channel.fire cordova.js:747
(anonymous function) cordova.js:220
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/impression.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.{my_url_name}.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If I instead bring in the Facebook SDK using the tag below:

```
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" style=""></script>
```

The site works in the Chrome desktop broswer but not on my iphone. I get the following error from the Safari inspector after deploying the app to my iphone.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (all.js, line 0)
```

Can anyone help me resolve this. If I have to do all my debugging through my iphone and emulators it will be very cumbersome.